# How to write # in pdf with pdflatex and lualatex?

Tags: pdf

For escaping `/` in pdf I must use `#2fx`, but I do not know how to write `#` characters in pdf. When I write `#`, I obviously get an error. When I use `\#`, it exactly writes in pdf, and when I use `\tl_to_str:n{#}`, I have `#` but I need exactly `#` character in pdf. Now you will see my example using `\#`, but in the pdf I have `\#` instead of `#`. Thanks everybody for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdf}
\begin{document}
test
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_object_new:nn{obj}{dict}
\pdf_object_write:nx{obj}{/Type\c_space_tl/test#2fx-test}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the proper way to fix this, but try `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pdf_object_write:nn { ne }` and then `\pdf_object_write:ne{obj}{/Type\c_space_tl/test#2fx-test}`. Also, if you're using `:nx` just because of `\c_space_tl`, you can replace it by `~`, then you don't need any expansion: `\pdf_object_write:nn{obj}{/Type~/test#2fx-test}`.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik Ok,but how in this case i can use # character as number of argument,if i will need in it?

Comment: But in that example you are not inside a macro, so `#2` is not an argument. If you're using `\pdf_object_write:nn` from inside a macro, then `#2` should be replaced by the second argument. Can you please post an example code for this case?

Comment: Sounds as if you actually want to use one of the l3str-convert macros, but I can't test now.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer How i can use this macros for # character? Can you please write an example and i will test it myself.

Comment: So,as i understood,there is no good way to solve problem with # character,to use it as a character and as number of argument?

Comment: Where i can find l3str-convert macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want what in pdflatex is provided by the `\pdfescapename`
command. The `pdftexcmds` package provides luatex emulation. With `expl3` you can use the commands of the `l3str-convert` module.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
test
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_object_new:nn{obj}{dict}
\str_set_convert:Nnnn\l_tmpa_str {test/slash}{}{utf8/name}
\pdf_object_write:nx{obj}{/Type\c_space_tl /\l_tmpa_str}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

which gives

```
 << /Type /test#2Fslash >>
```

If you know what you want to produce, you can insert the `#` e.g. like this:

```
\pdf_object_write:nx
  {obj}
  {/Type\c_space_tl /test\char_generate:nn{35}{12}2Fslash}
```

or

```
\pdf_object_write:nx
  {obj}
  {/Type\c_space_tl /test\token_to_str:N#2Fslash}
```